# j2objc - resolving object types

Tags: java, android, objective-c

I've installed j2objc and am trying to convert my package to objective-c. My classes reference each other and also JSONObject and JSONArray. I'm getting a a bunch of the following errors

> *classname* cannot be resolved to a type

How do i make sure these references resolve?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I've yet to see any success with using a language level converter to try to port any significant amount of code between platforms.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have j2objc defined as a system variable, here's what I did:

1. Place j2objc folder inside your java project folder (to simplify paths in terminal)
2. If your Java project package names are something like com.example.appName.ClassName.java
   -j2objc folder should be in same directory as com
3. In terminal, cd to ProjectName containing com
4. Place this in command line:

   j2objc-0.8.3/j2objc -use-arc -sourcepath com --ignore-missing-imports com/example/appName/*

The key you are probably missing is -sourcepath. use-arc and ignore-missing-imports are optional.